# How to call another components method in angular 4

Tags: angular

How to call the method of another component in angular 4. I have two component App component and dashboard component and I want to call a method of dashboard component from the app component.

Actually, there is no parent-child relationship between those 2 components, as the overview component is a routed component, so I can't use @ViewChild also

Comment: Your description is pretty vague, but I'd guess that, as for 90 percents of the question asking about interaction between components, the answer is: use a common service. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: @JB Nizet,Using common service only but when that service is calling from dashboard component i am passing some parameters, but i cannot get those parameters in app component

Comment: Have you at least clicked the link I posted and read the explanations and the example?

Comment: @JB Nizet that works.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and solved it this way:

First, I created a sampleService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    public update(message) {
        this.subject.next({message: message});
    }

    public listen() {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

In ComponentB, I injected SampleService and called its listen() method :

```
import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Subscription";
import {SampleService} from "find/to/path/sampleService";

export class ComponentB {
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(...,
        private sampleService: SampleService) {
        this.sampleService.listen().subscribe(message => { this.onSampleServiceUpdate(message); });
    }

    public onSampleServiceUpdate(message) {
        // now component B notified
    }
}
```

Then in Component A, I injected ComponentA and called its update() method:

```
import {SampleService} from "find/to/path/sampleService";

export class ComponentA {

    constructor(...,
        private sampleService: SampleService) {}

    export class ComponentB {
        // use this.smapleService.update("my message");
    }

}
```

Look at these codes:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6QJzFoJDMndA6RvSpsW6)